# Generating exe from PyQt program with py2exe

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I have this program which works fine in the shell [ http://pastebin.com/qsfJt8eE ]

But when I try to generate a .exe using the py2exe I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 470, in <module>
NameError: name 'ACCOUNT' is not defined
```

Why is this happening?

Relevant block of code (the end of whole file) looks like:

```
# line 455
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    try:
        acc = pickle.load(open("personal_account.p", "rb"))
        ACCOUNT = Account()  # line 460
        MAIN = MainFrame()
        BALANCE = BalanceFrame(MAIN)
        LOANS = LoansFrame(MAIN)
        BORROWS = BorrowsFrame(MAIN)
        POPUP = PopUp(MAIN, BALANCE, LOANS, BORROWS)
        MAIN.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    finally:
        pickle.dump(ACCOUNT.data, open("personal_account.p", "wb"))  # line 470
```

Comment: Please do not link to external pastebins. Post the relevant part of code in your question. Questions should be standalone as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect, that on line 459 the code fails to load pickle file thus does not set up `ACCOUNT` variable on following line.

Then on line 470 you try to use that variable and fail.